# Static html to Wordpress | Hamburger button not working any more

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have static website, after 2 year I decided to convert it to WordPress. I made all PHP code required to make this process and the website works fine on WordPress but the menu Hamburger button not working any more I do not know why?
http://floranow.ejad.solutions/
I will put the old static html header code and the new php one.

Old static html header:

```
    <header id="header">
    <nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>


            <div id="desktpMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left " >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >

                 <li id="home1"  class="scroll "><a href="#home">Home</a></li>  

                  <li id="section21" class="scroll"><a href="#section2">about us</a></li>

                  <li id="Process1" class="scroll"><a href="#Process">Process</a></li>

                  <li id="ourStories1" class="scroll"><a href="#ourStories">Our stories</a></li>

                  <li class="scroll "><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>

                  <li class="scroll "><a href="#">FAQS</a></li>

                <li class="scroll "><a href="#thfrm">Contact us</a></li>





                </ul>
            </div>
        </div><!--/.container-->



        <div id="mbmenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left " >
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >

                 <li class="scroll"><a href="#layerslider">Home</a></li>  


                  <li class="scroll"><a href="#section2">about us</a></li>

                  <li class="scroll"><a href="#Process">Process</a></li>

                  <li class="scroll"><a href="#ourStories">Our stories</a></li>

                <li class="scroll "><a href="#thfrm">Contact us</a></li>





                </ul>
            </div>



    </nav><!--/nav-->
</header><!--/header-->
```

new php one:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <title><?php bloginfo('name')?><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
    <?php if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ;?>/favicon.ico"/>
    <!-- core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/owl.transitions.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/style_common.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/style2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ?>/css/layerslider/css/layerslider.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


</head><!--/head-->

<body id="home"   class="homepage">




 <header id="header">
        <nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
            <div class="container">

  <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'ahmad_logo' ) ) : ?>
        <a class='navbar-brand' href='<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>'
        title='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>'
        rel='home' class="navbar-brand">
                <img src='<?php echo esc_url( get_theme_mod( 'ahmad_logo' ) );  ?>'
                     alt='<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>'
                     ></a>
  <?php endif; ?>
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>


                <div id="desktpMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left " >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                    <?php

                 echo     '<li id="home1"  class="scroll "><a href="../#home">Home</a></li>

                     <li id="section21" class="scroll"><a href="../#section2">about us</a></li>

                      <li id="Process1" class="scroll"><a href="../#Process">Process</a></li>

                       <li id="ourStories1" class="scroll"><a href="../#ourStories">Our Partners</a></li>

                      <li class="scroll "><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>

                    <li class="scroll "><a href="/faqs">FAQS</a></li>

                    <li class="scroll "><a href="/contact-us">Contact us</a></li> ';

?>




                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div><!--/.container-->

        </nav><!--/nav-->
    </header><!--/header-->
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Rather than comparing the static HTML to the PHP code, it would be easier to compare the static HTML to the HTML generated by PHP. When the page renders, use view source to see the generated PHP, then compare.

Comment: the same old file will generated but hamburger button do not work

Comment: Hamburger menu shows up when you make the window narrow, which suggests there must be a media query in the CSS, determining that it only shows up at small window sizes.